# Write a higher-order function, checkConsistentOutput()

Tags: javascript

This function should have two parameters: a function and a value. It should call the argument function with the value two times. If the callback function produces the same result twice, it should return the result of the function call, otherwise, it should return the string 'This function returned inconsistent results'

```
const checkThatTwoPlusTwoEqualsFourAMillionTimes = () => {
  for(let i = 1; i <= 1000000; i++) {
    if ( (2 + 2) != 4) {
      console.log('Something has gone very wrong :( ');
    }
  }
};

const addTwo = num => num + 2;

const timeFuncRuntime = funcParameter => {
  let t1 = Date.now();
  funcParameter();
  let t2 = Date.now();
  return t2 - t1;
};

// Write your code below
const time2p2 = timeFuncRuntime(checkThatTwoPlusTwoEqualsFourAMillionTimes);

const checkConsistentOutput(func, val) => {
  let checkOne = func(val);
  let checkTwo = func(val);
  if (checkOne === checkTwo){
    return checkOne;
  } else {
    return 'This function returned inconsisent results'
  }
}
```

I'm getting the error SyntaxError: Missing initializer in const declaration. please help me understand.

Comment: Typo. You forgot an `=` in `const something = value`.

Comment: You have a typo. `const checkConsistentOutput(func, val) => {` you're missing a `=`

Answer (score 0):

I'm seeing an error in the last const declaration that appears to be because it's missing an '='.

```
const checkConsistentOutput(func, val) => {
   ...
}
```

```
const checkConsistentOutput = (func, val) => {
   ...
}
```